# Can I add a VB.Net form to an ASP web Application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I am building a website in VS Community 2015 and I would like to add a few vb.net applications to the pages. I want to add 2 .exe's to each page, a text editor app. (like this one) and a ComboBox App. Can I just name the forms Form2 and Form3 and add them to the pages somehow. I know that the Combobox could easily be added using ASP code (i.e. Dropdown and LinkItem) but how would I go about adding something as complicated as an editor. The editor will be used to allow users to add stories to their membership pages. The Combobox will be used to allow the user to show or hide certain parts of their membership pages.

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: `Can I add a VB.Net form to an ASP web Application?` short answer **no**.

Comment: @Codexer : Long answer is probably "**no**" too. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent :) I concur

Comment: Ok Guy's I get it, lol

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of solutions. try CKEditor. HTML and JAVAscript implemented.[image: CKEditor]